# Atom IDE - How to remove popup function name list?

Tags: ide, atom-editor

I installed a couple of packets to enable the IDE in Atom. However, every time I type, a popup list comes up and it's rather annoying. I looked into the packet settings, but nothing worked to disable it...

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm7LC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is Auto completion. Try googling on how to disable it.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks, person who i've never met before in real life.